# find the maximum $\frac{\frac{x^2_{1}}{x_{2}}+\frac{x^2_{2}}{x_{3}}+\cdots+\frac{x^2_{n-1}}{x_{n}}+\frac{x^2_{n}}{x_{1}}}{x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, convex-optimization, convexity-inequality

give the postive intger $n\ge 2$,and postive real numbers $a<b$ if the real numbers such $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}\in[a,b]$ find the maximum of the value
$$\dfrac{\frac{x^2_{1}}{x_{2}}+\frac{x^2_{2}}{x_{3}}+\cdots+\frac{x^2_{n-1}}{x_{n}}+\frac{x^2_{n}}{x_{1}}}{x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}}$$

it seem the  polya-szego inequality   http://journalofinequalitiesandapplications.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/1029-242X-2013-591

Comment: @function sug It's an easy convexity. It's enough to check $x_i\in\{a,b\}$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: If it's so easy, why not formulate a decent answer?

Comment: @Han de Bruijn Because there are more an interesting problems they I need to solve. By the way we have four days for the posting of the proof.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: I have no proof, that's why I'm curious about yours.

Comment: I would use rearrangement inequality and claim that minimum is $1$, but maximum?

Answer (score 6):

Let $M$ is a maximum value (it exists because continuous function on compact gets there a maximum value) and
$$f(x_1,x_2,...x_n)=\frac{x_1^2}{x_2}+\frac{x_2^2}{x_3}+...+\frac{x_n^2}{x_1}-M(x_1+x_2+...+x_n).$$
Since  $f$ is a convex function for all $x_i$, we obtain
$$0=\max_{\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}\subset[a,b]}f=\max_{\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}\subset\{a,b\}}f$$
From here if $n$ is even we have $$M=\frac{\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{a}}{a+b}=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a}-1,$$
which occurs for $x_1=x_3=...=a$ and $x_2=x_4=...=b$.

If $n$ is odd we have for $n=2m+1$:
$$M=\frac{m\left(\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{a}\right)+a}{(m+1)a+mb},$$
which occurs for $x_1=x_3=...=x_{2m+1}=a$ and $x_2=x_4=...=x_{2m}=b$.

Comment: I`d need some explanation about the convexity of the function, but I really don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: @Rafa Budría because $\frac{\partial^2x_i}{\partial x_i^2}=\frac{2}{x_{i+1}}+\frac{2x_{i-1}}{x_i^3}>0$

Comment: Thank you! Still remains the other puzzling question ;-)

Comment: Could you please explain how you obtained the maximum for the discrete corner case, i.e., when $x_i\in\{a,b\}$?

Comment: @Hans For all $i$ we see that $f$ is a convex function of $x_i$. Thus, $f$ gets a maximum value for an extremal value of $x_i$, id est, for $x_i\in\{a,b\}$. .

Comment: You misunderstood me. I am asking about the maximum for the discrete corner case where $x_i\in\{a,b\}$, NOT the continuous case before its reduction to the discrete case. In other words, I am asking about how you reach the final conclusion how the $a$ and $b$ should be assigned to $x_i$.

Comment: @G Cab With your example, if  $n=4$ we have $\frac{a^2-ab+b^2}{ab}\geq\frac{2a+\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{a}}{3a+b}$ is true because it's $a(a-b)^2\geq0$.

Comment: @Hans It's a very ugly work.

Comment: That is even more reason to show it. Otherwise it is pretty mysterious. Please do write it out in your answer. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, you are right, sorry: I deleted my comment

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg - In general, positivity of second derivatives does not guarantee convexity in higher dimensions (e.g., $f(x,y)=xy$) so your reply to Rafa Budria's comment is not complete.

Comment: @uniquesolution I did not say that $f$ is a convex function. I said that $f$ is a convex function of $x_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: @uniquesolution: What you said was right. Michael Rozenberg is right that we only need convexity in each variable to reduce the problem to corner case. However, it happens that $f$ is indeed convex, since $\frac{x_i^2}{x_j}$ is convex $\forall i, j$ and the sum of them is convex while $-M\sum_i x_i$ is convex.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Would you mind writing out your proof for the final discrete case that the continuous case has reduced to? I am extremely curious about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a proof of the discrete case for Michael Rozenberg's reply, assuming $n\ge 2$ and therefore $M>1$.

Consider a cyclic word $x$ on $\{a,b\}^n$ maximizing $f$. We can write $f(x)$ as a linear function of the counts of the $n$ cyclic bigrams $x_i x_{(i+1)\bmod n}$:
$$f(x) = n_{aa} w(a,a) + n_{ab} w(a,b) + n_{ba} w(b,a) + n_{bb} w(b,b)$$
where $w(s,t)=\frac{s^2}{t} - M s$.

Because $M>1$, $w(b,b) < w(a,a)$ therefore $x\ne b^n$ and if $x$ contained an instance of $bb$, we could increase $f(x)$ by replacing it with $b$ and inserting another $a$ next to any $a$. Thus $n_{bb}=0$.

And because there are as many $ba$ bigrams as $ab$, we have:
$$f(x) = \left(n-2n_{ab}\right) w(a,a) + n_{ab} \left(w(a,b)+w(b,a)\right)$$
This is a linear function of $n_{ab}$ so the maximum is reached when $x$ is either of the form $a^n$ or $(ab)^* a?$. The former is never maximal because $M>1$, therefore Michael Rozenberg's construction is optimal.